# What is the name of the effect used in "Latte Art - iPhone app"? And how can be done for iphone application?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

First of all i will give the application video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK94HSM2AD8).
 What are the name of effects used in this application? How can i do this effects in iPhone application?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I guess no one is going to answer this, since this is not a standaard effect. I tink the developer spend a lot of time doing the math for the animation. You should really start trying to code the animation your self, then when you are stuck, post the a part of you code here one which you are stuk. Quetsions like: "How can I", "Give me an example" or "Need code for" are mostly not accepted on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry. But i only want to name of effects? And the question "how can i" is only learn to the development platform for this like cocos2d, unity etc. Not a "please give me a code or give me an example"!

Comment: I understand, but there is no one term for this kind of animation, it more like a water like animation with some kind of flow. This makes you question really broad and it just can't be answered with a: "oww it a .... animation". The animation used is probably some thing the developer work on for weeks and not just something he implemented from a default SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the specific name of all the effects are, it seems like there are a variety of image processing techniques being used.

The bit that looks like the photoshop liquify filter is a form of texture mapping, i.e. a texture is mapped to a 2d mesh. In this case dragging the screen deforms the vertices in the mesh, thus the image. The more vertices in the control mesh, the finer the detail in the distortion.

Look into texture mapping and (since it's iOS) glsl shaders.